# .net comapi assembly

Tags: .net, com

i have code, from http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid474AD07673DE318A1237D142E2BEF5E41CAFAA8B.aspx?s=opc#L1

```
 ComApi.CreateInstance(...)
```

and i have compiler error, that namespace 'ComApi' doesn't exist.
Which assembly must i add to project, to make it work.

Comment: Where did you get the name `ComApi` from? There is no such class in the .NET base class library.

Comment: edited my question. evrything work, only this place fails

Comment: Where id `OPC.Common` defined? Do you have the library anywhere? Did you add it as a reference?

Comment: @eba: That link doesn't work for me. Either way, my guess is that `ComApi` is defined in some other dependency code on the same site.

Comment: @Cody Gray - the link has a code listing that has at the top `using OPC.Common;`.

Comment: opc.common in my project, it doesnt have comapi inside it. thx for answers. i will dig more

Comment: Never mind; the link works now. But, as I suspected, check out this code from the same site: http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid9C50A5D341F19B4B74F251422575F422608F185C.aspx?s=comapi#L6

Comment: how u did it? i couldnt find it my self

Comment: @eba: I just did a search at the top for "ComApi", constrained to C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ComApi` class that the code you posted depends on is [defined elsewhere](http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid9C50A5D341F19B4B74F251422575F422608F185C.aspx?s=comapi#L6) on the same site.